# Shutting down NameNode at localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I use `bin/hdfs namenode -format` to start my hadoop-2.10.0 on my ECS,it can not work.
`SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at localhost/127.0.0.1`

I change my hosts file and add `172.16.74.149 cong`
so the errmsg becomes follows:

```
20/04/22 10:20:05 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
20/04/22 10:20:05 INFO namenode.FSImage: FSImageSaver clean checkpoint: txid = 0 when meet shutdown.
20/04/22 10:20:05 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at cong/172.16.74.149
************************************************************/
```

I can't understand why.
Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

At first I encounter this message, I thought it was the system error, and I check carefully, it dose not like an error, maybe it is a normal message, so I follow the document and finish those follow steps.[Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUFNx.jpg)